# How to set up pexpect expecting multiple outcomes

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

We have a scenario where we have 2 expectקג outcomes that we like to execute with.
Below, after sending "status" command, it can give possible outcomes.
'run' or 'not run'

eg

```
t.sendline('status')
i=t.expect('run')
if i!=0:
    t.sendline('start')
else:
    break
```

When we ran our script, it keeps getting stuck at `i=t.expect('run')` line and fails when
status returns 'not run'

How do we set it up such that:

1. It doesn't stop the script from exiting when executing `i=t.expect('run')` and continue to run.
2. We can use 2 expected outcomes in our script to execute an outcome.

Thanks all
Sincerely

Answer (score 5):

```
t.sendline('status')
i=t.expect(['run','not run'])
if(i==0):
    t.sendline('start')
else:
    break;
```

Source http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: See also: docs for the expect method: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect

Comment: Source link in the answer now gives a 404. Also unable to add a suggest edit with Sagar's link as suggest edit queue is full.